# Replacing a null value with the next null value in dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I am looking to replace all null and subsequent nulls in a pandas dataframe with the next non null value that is in the column:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

before_list = ['Apples',np.NAN,np.NAN,np.NAN,np.NAN,'Apples','Oranges',np.NAN,np.NAN,np.NAN,'Oranges','Bananna',np.NAN,np.NAN,'Bananna']
df=pd.DataFrame(before_list)
df
```

The final dataframe should be the same as the output from the following:

```
after_list = ['Apples','Apples','Apples','Apples','Apples','Apples','Oranges','Oranges','Oranges','Oranges','Oranges','Bananna','Bananna','Bananna','Bananna']
df_after_update=pd.DataFrame(after_list)
df_after_update
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance

Frank

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. It would be helpful to know what you've already tried based on your own research to resolve the issue. For example, pandas has the [fillna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) method, which seems exactly fit for purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
df.bfill(inplace=True)
```

Or you can use also as suggested by @G. Anderson :

```
df.fillna(method="bfill", inplace=True)
```